# Deleting a file in PHP

Tags: php, forms, loops

hope you guys can help me as I'm really stuck with this one.

I'm making part of a CMS where the users can view, upload and delete images stored in a directory. But when the user clicks delete, it just deletes the last image in the directory. It seems as though it's not getting the name of the image when the user clicks Delete.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
if (isset($_POST['deletebutton'])){
$link = "../../images/gallery/".$_POST['id'];
unlink($link);
}

if ($handle = opendir('../../images/gallery')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            echo "<div class='photobox'><img src='../../images/gallery/".$entry."' class='img'><input type='hidden' value='".$entry."' name='id'><input type='submit' class='deletebutton' name='deletebutton' value='Delete'></div>";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure the file permissions allow for the file to be deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to wrap each set of `<input/>`s in separate `<form/>` tags. If PHP sees more than one input with the same name, it just takes the last one. For example...

```
<form method="get" action="#">
  <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar" />
  <input type="submit" />
  <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="baz" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Regardless of which submit you click, the browser will encode the form as `?foo=bar&foo=baz`, which PHP will read in order and leave you with `$_REQUEST['foo'] == 'baz'`